# Angular Form Validation not working at all

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to get form validation to work in my web app for a while now without any luck.  So I tried to create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj2tu/) that works so I can then copy the code directly back to my app. However, I copied the code directly from the [AngularJS Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) page into the JSFiddle and it does not work... I have included the newest angular.min.js file into the fiddle. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    Name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="uName" required /><br />
    E-mail:
      <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="uEmail" required/><br />
    <div ng-show="form.uEmail.$dirty && form.uEmail.$invalid">Invalid:
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
    </div>

    Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.agree" name="userAgree" required />
    I agree: <input ng-show="user.agree" type="text" ng-model="user.agreeSign"
              required /><br />
    <div ng-show="!user.agree || !user.agreeSign">Please agree and sign.</div>

    <button ng-click="reset()" ng-disabled="isUnchanged(user)">RESET</button>
    <button ng-click="update(user)"
            ng-disabled="form.$invalid || isUnchanged(user)">SAVE</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

function Controller($scope) {
  $scope.master = {};

  $scope.update = function(user) {
    $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
  };

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
  };

  $scope.isUnchanged = function(user) {
    return angular.equals(user, $scope.master);
  };

  $scope.reset();
}
```

Comment: were you able to solve this? I am facing similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing ng-app="myapp"

Comment: if I do that, then the JSFiddle gives an error saying it cannot find it

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get this to work in JSFiddle either, but in my test app (VS 2013 with Angular 1.2.18) it works with this small change:

```
app.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
$scope.master = {};

$scope.update = function(user) {
    $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
};

$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
};

$scope.isUnchanged = function(user) {
    return angular.equals(user, $scope.master);
};

$scope.reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it without having to change your controller code or anything else. There are some issues with including the right library and taking the basic steps to run an Angular app, which makes this a good lesson in environment checking.

Namely: You forgot to include the Angular library in the jsfiddle and, I suppose, in your own environment. If you include it **and** add add in a `ng-app="myapp"` wrapper for Angular to find, it works just fine.

**[Here's the updated, working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHujk/)**

Problems like these can be really frustrating—I understand and have been in a situation many times where the logic of my code seems to work perfectly and I find out some library wasn't being included or that a basic need wasn't being filled. I would recommend always double checking your 'surroundings', or the environment that your code exists in. Make sure libraries are being served, there aren't any CDN issues, and that there aren't any typos throwing the inclusions off.

Hope this helps!

PS: when copying example code from a really big and well-developed project like angular, the first thought you should have if it doesn't work is that there's something in your environment that's throwing it off, since the team behind Angular and projects like it is extremely unlikely to have put faulty example code out. It happens, but it's more unlikely than there being a problem with the local environment.

Comment: Except my jsFiddle DOES include the newest Angular library. I added it to the external resources. So I am still unsure why it wasn't working

Comment: It looks like the only real difference between mine and yours id you put your `ng-app` in its own parent div

Comment: If you remove it from the external resources and include the angular framework, it works, so it's likely there's something going wrong with how jsfiddle includes `angular.min.js` that you included. What happens when you run the exact same thing in your browser?

here's another working example in JSbin: http://jsbin.com/qomahemi/1/edit?html,js,output .

I'm guessing it somehow has to do with how the external resource is being included

Comment: @MattHintzke removing the 'myapp' module declaration doesn't work in either environment I'm trying it out in; are you calling `ngApp` somewhere else? If you're not, the only other option is to manually initialize, which it doesn't seem you're doing (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap). Can you elaborate? :)